# My jQuery wrap method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm trying to use jQuery wrap but it doesn't work.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.taggify = function () {
        create(this);
        return this;
    };

    function create($theElement) {
        var $input = $('<input></input>')
            .attr('type', 'text')
            .attr('autocomplete', 'off')
            .css('border', 'none')
            .css('outline', 'none')
            .wrap('<li></li>');

        $input.on('keyup', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                var tagText = $input.val();
                var $span = $('<span class="tag-label"></span>');

                $span.text(tagText).wrap('<li class="tag-choice"></li>');
                $theElement.prepend($span);
            }
        });

        $theElement.append($input);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The result still doesn't have `<li>` tag wrapped around the input

Here's the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/noppanit/sryg5fk7/1/

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283292/my-jquery-wrap-method-doesnt-work/31283652#31283652

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just move your wrap code after append input element .

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sryg5fk7/7/)

```
 $theElement.append($input);
 $input.wrap('<li />');

 $theElement.prepend($span);
 $span.text(tagText).wrap('<li class="tag-choice"></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it using:

```
   (function ($) {
    $.fn.taggify = function () {
         var $input = $('<input />')
             .addClass('specialInput')
            .attr('type', 'text')
            .attr('autocomplete', 'off')
            .css('border', 'none')
            .css('outline', 'none')
            .wrap('<li />');

        $(this).append($input);

        return this;
    };


})(jQuery);

$('body').on('keyup','.specialInput',function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                $('<li class="tag-choice"><span class="tag-label">'+$(this).val()+'</span></li>').prependTo($(this).parent());

            }
        });
```

Looking at the console, the error surrounds trying to use the `.on()` command on a non DOM element

Comment: It still doesn't work I have also attached the jsfiddle which it doesn't work as well.

Comment: @toy make sure you are using at least jquery 1.11 and use the code exactly as above

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure why, but look like you wanna wrap the element that not exist yet. Unless wrap the element after `prepend` should work like so :

```
$theElement.append($input);
$input.wrap('<li></li>'); 

$theElement.prepend($span);
$span.text(tagText).wrap('<li class="tag-choice"></li>');
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/sryg5fk7/5/)**

*p/s : This only an alternative solution for your problem, not sure why the original code did't worked either.*

Answer (score -1):

How about using like this?

```
var $input = $('<li><input></input></li>')//wrap li here
            .find('input')//find input and use as you want
            .attr('type', 'text')
            .attr('autocomplete', 'off')
            .css('border', 'none')
            .css('outline', 'none');
```

I also noticed that you're using on method but this wouldn't work as the element is dynamically created. So replace this line:

```
 $input.on('keyup', function (e) {
```

With this:

```
 $(document).on('keyup', $input, function (e) { 
 //you may use closest parent element instead of document
```

[your updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sryg5fk7/2/)

Comment: I've included jsfiddle.